# Hilbert's Nullstellensatz and irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

In p.35 of Miranda's book *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*, the following theorem is stated and is called as Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

**Theorem.** Let $f\in \Bbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is an irreducible polynomial, and $h$ is a polynomial vanishing everywhere on the zero set of $f$. Then $f$ divides $h$.

But as I remember, the original Nullstellensatz is the following:

**Theorem.** Every maximal ideal of $\Bbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is of the form $(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)$.

How does the original Nullstellensatz imply the new one?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, what you're calling the original Nullstellensatz is actually a (quick consequence of a) special case of Miranda's version, not actually equivalent to it.

Comment: IIRC the Nullstellensatz really states that if $I$ is an ideal of $\Bbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ then the polynomials vanishing in all of $V(I)$ are themselves elements of $\sqrt{I}$. Here $I=(f)$, so Nullstellensatz says that there exists a positive integer $n$ such $h^n\in(f)$.

Comment: Anyway, this question is probably answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/598593/11619). I do want a bit of input from others before I use my [tag:abstract-algebra] dupehammer-vote.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks.

Comment: The Nullstellensatz is notorious for having many different meanings. The last one you called the 'original Nullstellensatz' is usually referred to as the 'Weak Nullstellensatz' since it is substantially weaker than the standard one mentioned by Jyrki.

Comment: It sounded to me that you are ok with closing this as a duplicate of the other (where there is an answer explaining the key step). If I misinterpreted, please give more details. Reopening this is also easy. Also, what @DanielApsley said.